# De-excitation and vibrational frequency

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, frequency, vibrations, nuclear-physics

By utilising energetic beams of particles it is possible to set atomic nuclei into vibration. For a certain nucleus the subsequent de-excitation results in the emission of photons of energy $1$ $MeV$. Use this information to make an estimate of the vibrational frequency of the nucleus, stating any assumptions that you make.

Using $E=hf$ I can calculate the frequency of the energetic beams. However I don't get the vibrational frequency bit...

Comment: the energy and frequency of the photon correspond to the difference between two energy levels in the quantized osillator.  Each level of the oscillator has a frequency, which is not necessarily the same as that of the photon.

Comment: I don't think we have covered that material yet ( quantized oscillator) Can you explain it in a simpler way?

Comment: for example, in a 1-dimensional harmonic oscillator, the spacing of the energy levels is constant and the spacing is twice the energy of the ground state, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator